# Finding local coordinates in Norway

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, norway

I want to convert WGS_1984_UTM_ZONE_33N to EUREF89 NTM, which is official geodetic datum in Norway. I have not found EUREF89 NTM in ArcMap, but  I believe the European Terrestrial Reference System 1989 (ETRS89) is on the same datum.

So converting to (ETRS89) will be same thing?

I have done it already, but not sure if the coordinates in meters are correct?

How do I confirm it?

Comment: Are you using a standard coordinate system or a local coordinate system? What have you researched/tried so far using ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: most likely UTM http://mapref.org/MapProjectionsNO.html

Comment: Are you working with data at the Kommune level or a smaller area? ArcGIS has a few Kommune coordinate reference systems, but I'll have to check on Monday when we added them. Look under National Grids, Norway.

Comment: mkennedy, Thanks.. I am working with smaller area. I have found out some kommune coordinate refrence system, but did not find the Fredrikstad kommune. I am bit confused about under which NTM zone Fredrikstad falls, is it NTM 10 or NTM 11 ?

Comment: It's right in the middle, isn't it? I managed to search NTM on a [Fredrikstad website](https://www.fredrikstad.kommune.no/sok/?q=ntm) and found 2 references to NTM 10.

Comment: mkennedy. Yes it is in NTM10. Takk for hjelpen